# How can I split an array into specified lines when printing?

Tags: swift, xcode, dictionary

New to software development, I'm working through Big Nerd Ranch's book 'Swift Programming'. One of the challenges set by the book is to print an array within a dictionary that contains 15 zip codes and to have them split across three lines in groups of five. The formatting must *exactly* match how it appears in the book.

I have tried to solve the issue using the information taught in the book with assistance from the developer documentation.

No dice.

This is what I need to print:

```
Caterham has the following zip codes: [111, 111, 111, 111, 111,
                                       222, 222, 222, 222, 222,
                                       333, 333, 333, 333, 333]
```

However this is the closest I can get...

```
var areaCodes = ["Caterham": [111, 111, 111, 111, 111], "Coulsdon": [222, 222, 222, 222, 222], "Purley": [333, 333, 333, 333, 333]]

var caterhamCodes : [Int] = []

for (_, values) in areaCodes {
    caterhamCodes += values
}

print("Caterham has the following codes: \(caterhamCodes[0...4]),")
print("                                  \(caterhamCodes[5...9]),")
print("                                  \(caterhamCodes[10...14]).")
```

which prints:

```
Caterham has the following postcodes: [111, 111, 111, 111, 111],
                                      [222, 222, 222, 222, 222],
                                      [333, 333, 333, 333, 333].
```

Essentially, I need what I have above minus some square brackets and without the punctuation after each time a block of zip codes is printed. The book specifies that I might need to use a parameter called terminator. It also mentions I might need to learn how to represent special characters in string literals.

I appreciate that this is probably a high level question with a simple answer, but I'm only a few weeks into learning, so I hope I can be forgiven for asking at least a few silly questions!

Comment: Aren't `[222, 222, 222, 222, 222]` associated with `"Coulsdon"`?

Comment: Maybe if you re-read the *Silver Challenge*, what's required is the formatting of All values in the dictionary, so that it doesn't overflow...

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the developer community and have a nice stay!
I am trying to put answer as simple as possible, so here is my attempt:

```
var areaCodes = ["Caterham": [111, 111, 111, 111, 111],
                 "Coulsdon": [222, 222, 222, 222, 222],
                 "Purley": [333, 333, 333, 333, 333]]
let codesArray = areaCodes.values.sorted(by: { $0[0] < $1[0] })
let caterhamString = "Caterham has the following zip codes: ["
var printString = caterhamString

for (index, area) in codesArray.enumerated() {
   for code in area {
      printString += "\(code), "
   }

   if index != codesArray.count - 1 {
      printString += "\n" + String(repeating: " ", count: caterhamString.count)
   }
}

print(printString.dropLast(2).appending("]"))
```

Hope this helps! Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way of getting the desired output :

```
let intro = "Caterham has the following zip codes: ["
let spaces = ",\n" + String(repeating: " ", count: intro.count)

let areaCodes = ["Caterham": [111, 111, 111, 111, 111], "Coulsdon": [222, 222, 222, 222, 222], "Purley": [333, 333, 333, 333, 333]]

let codes = areaCodes.values.sorted { $0[0] < $1[0] }

var output = intro +
    codes.map { $0.map{ String($0) }.joined(separator: ", ") }
    .joined(separator: spaces)
    + "]"

print(output)
```

Which prints

> ```
> Caterham has the following zip codes: [111, 111, 111, 111, 111,
>                                        222, 222, 222, 222, 222,
>                                        333, 333, 333, 333, 333]
> ```